# CLOS equivalent of a destructor

Tags: common-lisp, clos, cffi

I am using a cffi-powered wrapper library cffi and there are objects to clean up. I am wondering if I can forego the need to write the clean-up code (or mitigate the use of `with-smth` macros) by encapusalating such objects in classes with destructors. Can I do that?

Comment: since common lisp utilizes gc, it's not always clear when should the object be destroyed. to some extent [trivial garbage](https://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-garbage/) could help. But again, the object destruction moment is indeterminate, so i wouldn't rely on this for resource management.

Comment: @leetwinski hmm, ok, I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: @leetwinski A GC cares just about memory resources. A destructor is used for other resources: https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#finally